# Dataframe -- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, attributeerror

I am not able to understand why this error is there in the code. Yesterday it was working absolutely fine and I was getting the correct result.

```
for j in range(column): #Column is the number of columns in the dataframe 'traindata'
    if np.all(traindata.iloc[:, j] == 0): #Compare all values in a column to 0 
        traindata = traindata.drop(traindata.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)                
print(traindata.shape)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iloc'.
```

I tried to look for what the issue is, but haven't found the right answer

Comment: `traindata` is `None`.  Could you share the code where you define it?

Comment: Here is the code:     
    traindata = pd.read_csv('train.csv') 
    traindata = pd.DataFrame(traindata)

Comment: I am using Jupyter, and the code shared above is in a different block. But i tried to add it in the same block and ran the code, still I got the same error

Comment: Did you debug your code (maybe you are not showing all the relevant code)? Check also the state of train.csv.

Comment: @JeroenHeier I have shared the code that I am using. Please let me know your suggestion

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Code is shared below. Please let me know your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

The problem is from: `traindata = traindata.drop(traindata.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)`. You can check the value of traindata right after it by adding one line of code `print(traindata)`, you will see it returns 'None'.

you can change to:
`traindata.drop(traindata.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)`

However, you may receive new error (IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds) because you keep dropping columns.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in this line of code :

`traindata = traindata.drop(traindata.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)`
the function drop changes the type of traindata, because you're affecting its return value.

you should not affect the result because it's applied to the dataframe
you should replace that line of code with:

**`traindata.drop(traindata.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)`**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import validation_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)


traindata = pd.read_csv('santandertrain.csv')
traindata_copy = traindata.copy()
traindata = pd.DataFrame(traindata)
print(traindata.shape)
[row, column] = traindata.shape

# testdata = pd.read_csv('santandertest.csv')
# testdata_copy = testdata.copy()
# print(testdata.shape) # (49342, 4992)

# print(traindata.describe().T)
# print(traindata.isnull().sum()) There are no NA values


for j in range(column):
    if np.all((traindata.iloc[:, j]) == 0):
        traindata = traindata.drop(traindata.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(traindata.shape)
```

When I run this code below, .iloc works perfect with training data

```
print(traindata.iloc[1:10, 0:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the following in a Jupyter notebook:

```
df = df.drop(['B1','C1','D2','E1','G1','H1','I1','K1'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

In my case I got the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

The solution that worked for me was related to using inplace=True and assigning the result of the line to df. So, here I had to either assign the result to df by writing `df = df.drop...` or by using `inplace=True` and not assigning the expression to df.

My solution without an error is:

```
df = df.drop(['B1','C1','D2','E1','G1','H1','I1','K1'], axis=1)
```

For your case change to:

```
traindata = traindata.drop([j], axis=1)
```